# Problem with multiprocessing in python [OSError: [WinError 6] Invalid driver]

Tags: python-3.x, pipe, python-multiprocessing

First of all, I apologize for my English.

I have implemented a game of cards in python. I need to create several processes that run the function generarArbol in parallel. They are created at the beginning of the game, and each time the agent has to play, he sends to each process a message using a Pipe to generate another tree.

```
def play(self, table, canticos, cartasConocidas):
    if self.n_baza == 0:
        time = 1500 #tiempo maximo que se ejecutara cada proceso
        manager = Manager()
        self.nProcesos = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*4 #numero de procesos a crear, dependiendo de los cores de la maquina, 4 procesos por nucleo
        self.procesos = []
        self.mejores = manager.Queue()
        for _ in range(self.nProcesos):
            server, client = Pipe(duplex=False)
            p = Process(target=self.generarArbol, args=(time, server, self.name, self.nameA, self.nameB, self.mejores,)) #se crear el proceso con sus atributos
            p.daemon = True
            self.procesos.append(client) #lo incluimos en la lista de pipes
            p.start() #ejecutamos el proceso
    matriz = self.cards_matrix.returnInstance(self.n_baza, table) #se crea una instancia de la matriz aleatoria

    for s in self.procesos:
        s.send([copy(matriz), copy(table), copy(self.n_baza)]) #se reanudan los procesos y se ejecutan los arboles


def generarArbol(self, time, server, name, nameA, nameB, mejores):
    from Clases.MCTS_TuteState import TuteState
    while True:
        [matriz, table, n_baza] = server.recv() #espera hasta recibir mensaje
        initialState = TuteState(matriz, table, n_baza, name, nameA, nameB)
        arb = mcts(timeLimit=time)
        carta = arb.search(initialState=initialState)
        mejores.put(carta)
```

The problem is that this error appears in each of the processes when I execute it:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ConnectionBase.__del__ at 0x128F14B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\litoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 132, in __del__
    self._close()
  File "C:\Users\litoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 277, in _close
    _CloseHandle(self._handle)
OSError: [WinError 6] Controlador no válido
```

I think it's about the Pipe. I thought that it was a Windows problem, but I tried it in Ubuntu and it also gives the same error. I do not understand why.

Greetings.